# Please any one can tell me How to filter an array from array using predicate.?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an array

```
NSArray *arry = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1322",@"13222",@"13322",@"14322",@"13522",@"21322",@"11322",@"13212" ,nil];
```

and I want to get array having object

```
@"1322",@"13222",@"13322",@"13212"
```

can you please tell me how to use predicate for this filter.

Comment: Any criteria for this?

Comment: It is unclear how you want to filter. For example, why is `@"13222"` included in the result, but `@"11322"` is not??

Comment: let i have four objects(a,b,g,d) and i want to retrive only those four(a,b,g,d) objects from array of all objects(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,....z).NOTE:-it is not like retrieving first four objects.

Comment: Are you aware of having written a question and three comments without  explaining what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question (and the comments) correctly.

To find all objects in `array` that are contained in another array `wanted`,
you can use the "SELF IN %@" predicate:

```
NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1322",@"13222",@"13322",@"14322",@"13522",@"21322",@"11322",@"13212" ,nil];
NSArray *wanted = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1322", @"13522", @"999", nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", wanted];
NSArray *filtered = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"%@", filtered);
```

Output:

```
(
1322,
13522
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like [c]'1*1*1'"];
NSArray *arry = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"1322",@"13222",@"13322",@"14322",@"13522",@"21322",@"11322",@"13212", nil];
NSArray *resltArry = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *p = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF like [c]'13***'"];
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"11321", @"13121", @"23121", @"1111", nil];
NSArray *resultArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:p];
NSLog(@"%@",resultArray);
```

o/p

(
    13121,

)

you can also refer this link
[thisone](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/2010/10/19/searching-arrays-with-nspredicate-and-blocks.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *yourArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1322",@"13222",@"13322",@"14322",@"13522",@"21322",@"11322",@"13212" ,nil];
NSArray *filter = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1322", @"13522", nil];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF IN %@", filter];

NSArray *filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

This `filteredArray` will contain your filtered data. I think it will work as well.

Comment: Why do you need to copy the accepted answer and answer again..?